# Jquery - Select multiply divs, on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

So I need, that when I mouseover `#3`. Both `#1` and `#2` are getting a specific css class.
Same goes if i hover `#5`, then all divs gets the css class.

And when they are not hovered anymore, the class removes from the divs.

```
<div class="rateStar"><a href="#1"><img src="/images/images/stars.png"/></a></div>
<div class="rateStar"><a href="#2"><img src="/images/images/stars.png"/></a></div>
<div class="rateStar"><a href="#3"><img src="/images/images/stars.png"/></a></div>
<div class="rateStar"><a href="#4"><img src="/images/images/stars.png"/></a></div>
<div class="rateStar"><a href="#5"><img src="/images/images/stars.png"/></a></div>
```

But Im a bit lost on how this can be done, can some one help me ?

Comment: Any specific logic to apply css class..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/). It can be used like this:

```
$('.rateStar').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).prevAll('.rateStar').addClass('glow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.rateStar').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.rateStar').removeClass('newclass');
    $(this).prevAll('.rateStar').addClass('newclass');
});
```

Comment: Ehm did you just take my answer?

Comment: And now you changed the class :P

Comment: Yes, you can say this is copy of your answer, but when I saw your answer and it matches to my `logic` then I changed the `class name`. Also in my `answer` it `removes` the `previously applied class`, then applied the `new one`.

Answer (score 0):

something look like this

js

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $('div').not($(this)).stop().animate({
        opacity: .3
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, 250);
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LCMSz/)